# Android DialogFragment takes empty list from arguments

Tags: java, android, dialog, arguments

I'm trying to pass LinkedList of selected items to DialogFragment and then if user presses delete button pass this list to method that deletes these items in my activity class. However i get empty list in DialogFragment.

I checked many times in debugger that my list of selected items is not empty but i get empty one from getArguments().getSerializable()

Dialog class

```
public class MyDialog extends AppCompatDialogFragment {
public static final String DIALOG_TAG = "Dialog window";
private MyDialogListener listener;
private DialogOption dialogOption;

public MyDialog(DialogOption dialogOption) {
    this.dialogOption = dialogOption;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public android.app.Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view;

    switch (dialogOption) {
        case DIALOG_ADD:
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_addtheme, null);
            final EditText editTextThemeName = view.findViewById(R.id.editText_themeName);

            builder.setView(view)
                    .setTitle("Add Theme")
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        }
                    })
                    .setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            String stringThemeName = editTextThemeName.getText().toString();
                            listener.addTheme(new Theme(stringThemeName));
                        }
                    });
            break;

        case DIALOG_DELETE:
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_deletetheme, null);

            builder.setView(view)
                    .setTitle("Delete themes")
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                        }
                    })
                    .setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            LinkedList<Theme> toDelete = (LinkedList<Theme>) getArguments().getSerializable("To delete");
                            listener.removeThemes(toDelete);
                        }
                    });
            break;

        case DIALOG_EDIT:
    }
    return builder.create();
}

@Override
public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    listener = (MyDialogListener) context;
}

public interface MyDialogListener {
    void addTheme(Theme theme);

    void removeThemes(LinkedList<Theme> themes);
}
```

}

Adapter class

```
public class ThemeListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ThemeListAdapter.ThemeViewHolder> {
private LinkedList<Theme> themeList;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private DictionaryActivity context;
private ActionMode actionMode;
private boolean multiSelect = false;
private LinkedList<Theme> selectedItems = new LinkedList<>();
private ArrayList<View> views = new ArrayList<>();
private MenuItem editItem;

public ThemeListAdapter(Context context, LinkedList<Theme> themeList) {
    this.themeList = themeList;
    this.context = (DictionaryActivity) context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ThemeViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.themelist_item, parent, false);
    return new ThemeViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ThemeViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    views.add(holder.itemView);
    holder.themeName.setText(themeList.get(position).getName());
    holder.wordsCount.setText(themeList.get(position).getWords().size() + " word(s)");
    holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            if (actionMode != null) {
                return false;
            }

            actionMode = context.startSupportActionMode(actionModeCallback);
            editItem = actionMode.getMenu().findItem(R.id.edit);
            selectItem(position, holder);

            return true;
        }
    });

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (multiSelect) {
                selectItem(position, holder);
            }
        }
    });

}

private ActionMode.Callback actionModeCallback = new ActionMode.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.longclick_toolbar_menu, menu);
        multiSelect = true;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.delete:
                if (selectedItems.size() != 0) {
                    Bundle data = new Bundle();
                    data.putSerializable("To delete", selectedItems);
                    context.openDialog(DialogOption.DIALOG_DELETE, data);
                    mode.finish();
                }
                return true;
            case R.id.edit:
                context.openDialog(DialogOption.DIALOG_EDIT);
                mode.finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        actionMode = null;
        multiSelect = false;

        for (View view : views) {
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }

        selectedItems.clear();
    }
};

private void selectItem(int position, ThemeViewHolder holder) {
    Theme item = themeList.get(position);

    if (selectedItems.contains(item)) {
        selectedItems.remove(item);
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    } else {
        selectedItems.add(item);
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorSelected));
    }

    if (selectedItems.size() > 1) {
        editItem.setVisible(false);
    } else {
        editItem.setVisible(true);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return themeList.size();
}

public static class ThemeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView themeName;
    public TextView wordsCount;
    public View itemView;

    public ThemeViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.itemView = itemView;
        themeName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_themeName);
        wordsCount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_wordsCount);
    }
}
```

}

Activity class

```
public class DictionaryActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
implements MyDialogListener {

private static final String THEMES_FILE = "themes.srl";
private LinkedList<Theme> themeList = new LinkedList<>();
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private ThemeListAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dictionary);
    setTitle(R.string.activity_dictionary_title);
    loadThemes();
    checkNoThemesText();
    initToolBar();
    initRecyclerView();
    initFab();
}

private void checkNoThemesText() {
    TextView noThemeText = findViewById(R.id.textview_no_theme);

    if (themeList.size() == 0) {
        noThemeText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        noThemeText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}

private void initToolBar() {
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_activity_dictionary);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}

private void initRecyclerView() {
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_themes);
    adapter = new ThemeListAdapter(this, themeList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
}

private void initFab() {
    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            openDialog(DialogOption.DIALOG_ADD);
        }
    });
}

void openDialog(DialogOption dialogOption) {
    MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog(dialogOption);
    dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), DIALOG_TAG);
}

void openDialog(DialogOption dialogOption, Bundle data) {
    MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog(dialogOption);
    dialog.setArguments(data);
    dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), DIALOG_TAG);
}

private void loadThemes() {
    try (FileInputStream fileInput = openFileInput(THEMES_FILE);
         ObjectInputStream objectInput = new ObjectInputStream(fileInput)) {
        themeList = (LinkedList<Theme>) objectInput.readObject();
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void saveThemes() {
    try (FileOutputStream fileOutput = openFileOutput(THEMES_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
         ObjectOutputStream objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutput)) {
        objectOutput.writeObject(themeList);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.dictionary_toolbar_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            Toast.makeText(DictionaryActivity.this, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public void addTheme(Theme theme) {
    themeList.add(theme);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    checkNoThemesText();
    saveThemes();
}

@Override
public void removeThemes(LinkedList<Theme> themes) {
    themeList.removeAll(themes);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    checkNoThemesText();
    saveThemes();
}
```

}